# Regarding java application hosting in github

Tags: github

I am planning to create an application for helping building, residents, etc constructors and their respective suppliers (who would be providing resources required to construct buildings like cement, bricks, etc) to coordinate with each other. The suppliers will list out the materials along with their prices (based on location, market situation etc) and constructors will able to choose appropiate suppliers based on theri budget. Many more features can be added like constructors will list out their current projects and suppliers may bid on those, rating, commenting, etc.

What are your views about hosting the app in github? Will I be able to get developers to work on it?

Comment: One for /* Programmers */ rather than stackoverflow?

Comment: You mean hosting the code repository, right? Not actually hosting the running app?

Comment: Yes...code repo to get help from experts for developing app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the place where to ask this, but yes - I think github is a good place. 
But why not also to create a mirror at google-code for example, isn't this possible? 
I wqould also encourage you to participate at technical forums, and if the  forums allow you - 
 add a link to the github repo in your signature.

Comment: Ok. Actually I participated in SanHack (http://www.sanitationhackathon.org/) and from there the idea came to my mind. I already have developed some code and looking forward to get something usefull out of it. I will look for googlr code too. Thank you for the suggestion :)